# Question on geometrical/continuous probability

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

An infinite floor is laid up of square tiles of side length $20 cm$. A small circular plate of radius $5 cm$ is set rolling. When it falls flat, find the probability that the plate is
(a) entirely within one square
(b) on four squares

Comment: Make clear to yourself where the center of the plate can be to satisfie (a) or (b) respectiviely. What percentage of the floor do these areas make up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the regions where the center of you plate is allowed to land to satisfie (a) and (b) respectively:

[image]

The square areas are of sidelength $10$ cm and the circles are of radius $5$ cm. Look at the percentage of the gray area per floor tile.

Comment: What if the centre of the plate doesn't lie on the corner but inside a square.

Comment: The corners are not important. I am _only_ talking about the inside of the gray areas! If the plates center is inside the gray, the condition is satisfied. Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Yeah, I understood what you were saying. Thank you

Comment: @hanzala In case you are unsure about the numerical results: (a) $\frac14$ and (b) $\frac\pi{16}$.